# Trying to get days, hour, and minutes between now and DATETIME IN MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the days, hours and minutes between the current date and hour and a DATETIME field in MySQL and PHP. I need to get the following information:

x days, x hours and x minutes to complete.

```
SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(),FECHA_FIN) AS DAY,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),FECHA_FIN)-TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(),FECHA_FIN)*24 AS HOUR,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),FECHA_FIN)-TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),FECHA_FIN)*60 AS MINUTE FROM ARTICULOS
```

Comment: All the above code used is SQL. This can be calculated within PHP, but where do you need it done?

Comment: I need to show only in php, but it doesn't get the right information. FECHA_FIN is for example (14/05/2013 19:00:01)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $dbc = [connection details here];
   $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT FETCHA_FIN FROM ARTICULOS;");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
   {
       $dbtime = $row[0];
       $now = date("d/m/Y h:i:s");
       $difference = $now-$dbtime;
       echo "Time to complete: " . date("h", $difference) . " hours, " . date("i", $difference) . " minutes and " . date("s", $difference) . " seconds.";
   }
?>
```

Unfortunately, I don't have time to test the above code, but it should work correctly, as I have used similar code before.

Comment: If I want to get the days too: date("d", $difference)? I tried this, but It gets information not right

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), FECHA_FIN) / 1440) as Days
    , FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), FECHA_FIN) % 1440 / 60) as Hours
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), FECHA_FIN) % 60 as Minutes
FROM ARTICULOS;
```

Comment: I have not a FECHA_FIN type TIMESTAMP in my table, it is DATETIME

Comment: why this does not return the remaining days?

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF is only for TIMESTAMPS fields? then Have I to use DATEDIFF() or TIMEDIFF()?

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF works for all date/time related field type.  You can even mix parameters... the first can be a TIMESTAMP while the second is a DATE etc.